# Not able to run the sample code on firefox and chrome on Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Details :
Selenium :3.5.3
chrome :Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
package website;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Neddoc_chrome {

 public static String driverPath = "/Users/snigdhanarain/Desktop";
 public static WebDriver driver;


public static void main(String []args) {
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/snigdhanarain/Documents/chrome");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
}
}
```

Error I am facing is as below :-

> Error getting : in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   driver executable is a directory:
>   /Users/snigdhanarain/Documents/chrome

Comment: Error getting : in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: /Users/snigdhanarain/Documents/chrome

Comment: same code for firefox …-

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using wrong binary.

`.exe` is binary is only specifically designed for Windows, `.exe` extension is reserved for Windows and it won't work in Mac.

You need to download Mac OS specific binary from below URL :-

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

Similarly, download the Mac OS binary from below URL :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

The code will be like :-

```
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/sn‌​igdhanarain/Document‌​s/geck");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("google.com");
 }
}
```

Comment: shubham i tried the same by downloading it from url u have given 
public class Neddoc {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/Users/snigdhanarain/Documents/geck");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 
            

           
         driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            }
 }
But still its not working and giving 1504701197208 addons.manager DEBUG Application has been upgraded

Comment: Yes it will be fail because you are using wrong argument instead of using webdriver.firefox.marionette .. Use webdriver.gecko.driver